# How to get logo url using a store id in the backend?

Tags: magento-2.1, url, image, backend, helper

I'm trying to get url of the front-end logo inside a custom helper method in the backend, but I get stuck on getting a file using theme model. All I have is: *store id*, *theme id*, *theme model* and a *filename*:

```
/**
 * Retrieve default store logo image URL from design config or theme
 *
 * @param null $storeId
 * @return string
 */
protected function getDefaultStoreLogoUrl($storeId = null)
{
    $folderName = \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Logo::UPLOAD_DIR;
    $storeLogoPath = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'design/header/logo_src',
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );

    $path = $folderName . '/' . $storeLogoPath;
    $logoUrl = $this->_urlBuilder
            ->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]) . $path;

    if ($storeLogoPath !== null && $this->isFile($path)) {
        $url = $logoUrl;
    } else {
        $themeId = (int)$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'design/theme/theme_id',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Model\ResourceModel\Theme\Collection $themeCollection */
        $themeCollection = $this->themeFactory->create();
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Model\Theme $theme */
        $theme = $themeCollection->getItemById($themeId);

        // ..... I'm stuck here
    }

    return $url;
}
```

I need asset for the theme frontend, but I don't know how to access it. It's should be something similar to the **`Block/Logo`'s code**:

```
$url = $this->assetRepository->getUrlWithParams(
    'images/logo.svg',
    [
        '_secure' => $this->_request->isSecure()
    ]
);
```

But inside the backend `$this->assetRepository` returns a backend asset :( and result url looks like:

```
http://baseurl.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/logo.svg
```

when I expect to get url like:

```
http://baseurl.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg
```

The question is: **how to get the frontend asset for specific theme in the backend?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to custom helper this dependency

```
\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation,
...
$this->emulation = $emulation;
```

and then in code before fetching logo run this

```
$this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
```

Once you finish what you wanted just restore original environment

```
$this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Please, update your answer with this line: `$this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true)`, becouse the "force" parameter is set as false by-default (in this case the method does not work for the default store: `if ($storeId == $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() && !$force) {
            return;
        }` https://gyazo.com/882f14048dbe4455acf824de241ccbb3 ).

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau done